# Divide combined username and password used in AUTH PLAIN to use in AUHT LOGIN to use with SMTP

Tags: authentication, smtp

I am trying to send an email through telnet using a SMTP server through Telnet

For AUTH PLAIN authentication I can use this string that is the username and password combined (ex: dGhpc0lzTXlVc2VybmFtZVRoaXNJc015UGFzc3dvcmQ=)

Now I need to use AUTH LOGIN to authenticate instead of AUTH PLAIN, which means I need the username and password separated.

My question is:
How can I "divide" this string?
Or, is there a way to find out the username and password if I authenticated through LOGIN PLAIN so that I can later use it in AUTH LOGIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string used by AUTH PAIN is simply a combination of the username and the password encoded in base 64. To divide it, we can decode from base 64 and try to divide them

The first part of the string is the username and the second is the password

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `openssl` instead of `telnet`. If you don't have the username and the password separately to start with, you base64-decode the `PLAIN` string, split it at the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), and then base64-encode the username and the password separately.